# Safe partitions to delete from old Windows install on second drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I recently bought a SSD and I installed Windows on it. Before the install I disconnected the Hard Drive (with Windows install) and repluged it once I was able to boot on the SSD.

Then, I created a new partition on the Hard Drive and moved all my important files on it. Finally I deleted the Windows partition, but I see 2 "remaining" partition : EFI System Partition and Reserved Partition.

Is it safe to delete these two partitions?

Disk 1 is SSD and Disk 2 is Hard Drive

[image]

Comment: It is safe to delete those partitions on the HDD neither partition is being used on the HDD.

Answer (score 1):

"Before the install I disconnected the Hard Drive (with Windows install) and repluged it once I was able to boot on the SSD."

If you did this, then it is safe to delete those 2 partitions.

"EFI System Partition and Reserved Partition."